# Reading user input using Java command line

Tags: java, command-line

I am new to Java, I wrote a program to accept some values from a user and make some manipulation, but I am getting an error and I don'i know what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Computronix{

    public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int order;
    double total;
    double s_cost=1200000;
    double l_cost=900000;
    System.out.println("Enter number of laptop you need to purchase");
    order = input.nextInt();

        if(order<=0){
            System.out.println("Please Order one laptop or more ");
        }
        elseif(order>0 && order<25){
            total = order*s_cost;
            System.out.println("The total cost is "+ total);

        }
        elseif(order>=25){
            total = order*l_cost;
            System.out.println("The total cost is "+ total);
        }   

    }

}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
**C:\Users\Internally-root\Desktop\helow>javac Computronix.java
Computronix.java:17: error: ';' expected
            elseif(order>0 && order<25){
                                       ^
Computronix.java:22: error: ';' expected
            elseif(order>=25){
                             ^
2 errors**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elseif` is not a valid Java keyword. It should be: `else if` (please note space between else and if)

```
elseif(order>0 && order<25) //Invalid

else if(order>0 && order<25) //Valid
```

Answer (score 8):

Java is strongly typed language

```
       elseif(order>0 && order<25){
```

Should be

```
       else if(order>0 && order<25){
```

Space between else and if

Answer (score 5):

You missed a space between `else` and `if`. `elseif` is not a valid keyword.

Answer (score 1):

For

```
elseif(order>0 && order<25)
```

instead use

```
else if(order>0 && order<25)
```

Hierarchy of `else if`:

```
  if (){
    //do something
    }else if(){
    //do something different
    }else{
    //some something else all together
    }
```